# SQL Performance multiple exclusion from the same table

Tags: sql, performance

I have a table where I have a list of people, lets say i have 100 people listed in that table

I need to filter out the people using different criteria's and put them in groups, problem is when i start excluding on the 4th-5th level, performance issues come up and it becomes slow

```
with lst_tous_movements as (
    select
        t1.refid_eClinibase
        t1.[dthrfinmouvement]
        t1.[unite_service_id]
        t1.[unite_service_suiv_id]
    from sometable t1
)

,lst_patients_hospitalisés as (
    select distinct
        t1.refid_eClinibase
    from lst_tous_movements t1
    where
    t1.[dthrfinmouvement] = '4000-01-01'
)
,lst_patients_admisUIB_transferes as (
    select distinct
        t1.refid_eClinibase
    from lst_tous_movements t1
    left join lst_patients_hospitalisés t2 on t1.refid_eClinibase = t2.refid_eClinibase
    where
    t1.[unite_service_id] = 4
    and t1.[unite_service_suiv_id] <> 0 
    and t2.refid_eClinibase is null
)
,lst_patients_admisUIB_nonTransferes as (
    select distinct
        t1.refid_eClinibase
    from lst_tous_movements t1
    left join lst_patients_admisUIB_transferes t2 on t1.refid_eClinibase = t2.refid_eClinibase
    left join lst_patients_hospitalisés t3 on t1.refid_eClinibase = t3.refid_eClinibase
    where

    t1.[unite_service_id] = 4
    and t1.[unite_service_suiv_id] = 0  
    and t2.refid_eClinibase is null
    and t3.refid_eClinibase is null
)
,lst_patients_autres as (
    select distinct
        t1.refid_eClinibase
    from lst_patients t1
    left join lst_patients_admisUIB_transferes t2 on t1.refid_eClinibase = t2.refid_eClinibase 
    left join lst_patients_hospitalisés t3 on t1.refid_eClinibase = t3.refid_eClinibase
    left join lst_patients_admisUIB_nonTransferes t4 on t1.refid_eClinibase = t4.refid_eClinibase
    where
    t2.refid_eClinibase is null
    and t3.refid_eClinibase is null
    and t4.refid_eClinibase is null
)
```

as you can see i have a multi level filtering out going on here...

- 1st i get the people where t1.[dthrfinmouvement] = '4000-01-01'
- 2nd i get the people with another criteria EXCLUDING the 1st group
- 3rd i get the people with yet another criteria EXCLUDING the 1st and
  the 2nd group
- etc..

when i get to the 4th level, my query takes 6 - 10 seconds to complete

is there any way to speed this up ?

this is my dataset i'm working with:

```
+------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| refid_eClinibase | nodossierpermanent_eClinibase | dthrfinmouvement | unite_service_id | unite_service_suiv_id |
+------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|            25611 | P0017379                      | 2013-04-27       |               58 |                     0 |
|            25611 | P0017379                      | 2013-05-02       |                4 |                     2 |
|            25611 | P0017379                      | 2013-05-18       |                2 |                     0 |
|            85886 | P0077918                      | 2013-04-10       |               58 |                     0 |
|            85886 | P0077918                      | 2013-05-06       |                6 |                    12 |
|            85886 | P0077918                      | 4000-01-01       |               12 |                     0 |
|            91312 | P0083352                      | 2013-07-24       |                3 |                    14 |
|            91312 | P0083352                      | 2013-07-24       |               14 |                     3 |
|            91312 | P0083352                      | 2013-07-30       |                3 |                     8 |
|            91312 | P0083352                      | 4000-01-01       |                8 |                     0 |
|            93835 | P0085879                      | 2013-04-30       |               58 |                     0 |
|            93835 | P0085879                      | 2013-05-07       |                4 |                     2 |
|            93835 | P0085879                      | 2013-05-16       |                2 |                     0 |
|            93835 | P0085879                      | 2013-05-22       |               58 |                     0 |
|            93835 | P0085879                      | 2013-05-24       |                4 |                     0 |
|            93835 | P0085879                      | 2013-05-31       |               58 |                     0 |
|            93836 | P0085880                      | 2013-05-20       |               58 |                     0 |
|            93836 | P0085880                      | 2013-05-22       |                4 |                     2 |
|            93836 | P0085880                      | 2013-05-31       |                2 |                     0 |
|            97509 | P0089576                      | 2013-04-09       |               58 |                     0 |
|            97509 | P0089576                      | 2013-04-11       |                4 |                     0 |
|           102787 | P0094886                      | 2013-04-08       |               58 |                     0 |
|           102787 | P0094886                      | 2013-04-11       |                4 |                     2 |
|           102787 | P0094886                      | 2013-05-21       |                2 |                     0 |
|           103029 | P0095128                      | 2013-04-04       |               58 |                     0 |
|           103029 | P0095128                      | 2013-04-10       |                4 |                     1 |
|           103029 | P0095128                      | 2013-05-03       |                1 |                     0 |
|           103813 | P0095922                      | 2013-07-02       |               58 |                     0 |
|           103813 | P0095922                      | 2013-07-03       |                4 |                     6 |
|           103813 | P0095922                      | 2013-08-14       |                6 |                     0 |
|           105106 | P0097215                      | 2013-08-09       |               58 |                     0 |
|           105106 | P0097215                      | 2013-08-13       |                4 |                     0 |
|           105106 | P0097215                      | 2013-08-14       |               58 |                     0 |
|           105106 | P0097215                      | 4000-01-01       |                4 |                     0 |
|           106223 | P0098332                      | 2013-06-11       |                1 |                     0 |
|           106223 | P0098332                      | 2013-08-01       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106223 | P0098332                      | 4000-01-01       |                1 |                     0 |
|           106245 | P0098354                      | 2013-04-02       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106245 | P0098354                      | 2013-05-24       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106245 | P0098354                      | 2013-05-29       |                4 |                     1 |
|           106245 | P0098354                      | 2013-07-12       |                1 |                     0 |
|           106280 | P0098389                      | 2013-04-07       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106280 | P0098389                      | 2013-04-09       |                4 |                     0 |
|           106416 | P0098525                      | 2013-04-19       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106416 | P0098525                      | 2013-04-23       |                4 |                     0 |
|           106444 | P0098553                      | 2013-04-22       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106444 | P0098553                      | 2013-04-25       |                4 |                     0 |
|           106609 | P0098718                      | 2013-05-08       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106609 | P0098718                      | 2013-05-10       |                4 |                    11 |
|           106609 | P0098718                      | 2013-07-24       |               11 |                    12 |
|           106609 | P0098718                      | 4000-01-01       |               12 |                     0 |
|           106616 | P0098725                      | 2013-05-09       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106616 | P0098725                      | 2013-05-09       |                4 |                     1 |
|           106616 | P0098725                      | 2013-07-27       |                1 |                     0 |
|           106698 | P0098807                      | 2013-05-16       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106698 | P0098807                      | 2013-05-22       |                4 |                     6 |
|           106698 | P0098807                      | 2013-06-14       |                6 |                     1 |
|           106698 | P0098807                      | 2013-06-28       |                1 |                     0 |
|           106714 | P0098823                      | 2013-05-20       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106714 | P0098823                      | 2013-05-21       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106714 | P0098823                      | 2013-05-24       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106729 | P0098838                      | 2013-05-21       |               58 |                     0 |
|           106729 | P0098838                      | 2013-05-23       |                4 |                     1 |
|           106729 | P0098838                      | 2013-06-03       |                1 |                     0 |
|           107038 | P0099147                      | 2013-06-25       |               58 |                     0 |
|           107038 | P0099147                      | 2013-06-28       |                4 |                     1 |
|           107038 | P0099147                      | 2013-07-04       |                1 |                     0 |
|           107038 | P0099147                      | 2013-08-13       |               58 |                     0 |
|           107038 | P0099147                      | 2013-08-15       |                4 |                     6 |
|           107038 | P0099147                      | 4000-01-01       |                6 |                     0 |
|           107082 | P0099191                      | 2013-06-29       |               58 |                     0 |
|           107082 | P0099191                      | 2013-07-04       |                4 |                     6 |
|           107082 | P0099191                      | 2013-07-19       |                6 |                     0 |
|           107157 | P0099267                      | 4000-01-01       |               13 |                     0 |
|           107336 | P0099446                      | 4000-01-01       |                6 |                     0 |
+------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

thanks.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle?  It's not clear to me what you want at the end of your query.  Is it just the final filtered set, or all the sets?  What db are you using?

Comment: Hi, at the end of query i will have the same dataset but with the groups assigned for each person in a new column, by doing left joins i can say this person belongs in this group...i'm outside right now, i will post as much more info as i can when i get home, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to understand exactly what all your rules are from the question, but the general approach should be to add a "Grouping" column to a singl query that uses a `CASE` statement to categorize the people.

The conditions in a CASE are evaluated in order, so that if the first criteria is met, then the subsequent criteria are not even evaluated for that row.

Here is some code to get you started....

```
select  t1.refid_eClinibase
        ,t1.[dthrfinmouvement]
        ,t1.[unite_service_id]
        ,t1.[unite_service_suiv_id]
        CASE    WHEN [dthrfinmouvement] = '4000-01-01' THEN 'Group1 Label'
                WHEN condition2 = something THEN 'Group2 Label'
                ....
                WHEN conditionN = something THEN 'GroupN Label'
                ELSE 'Catch All Label'
        END as person_category
from sometable t1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer, however in my case the CASE WHEN approach would not work because the same person can fall into different categories where i need for the same person to STAY in the original category that was assigned to them in order, i hope my explanation is a bit clear, thanks

Comment: In that case, (which isn't at all clear in your question), I would go the route of making each category its own column in the view with a boolean indicating if a row is a member of that category.  BTW, you may want to edit the question as your use of EXCLUDING (in all caps) tends to indicated that the grouping are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Hi, it has been awhile i put my hands on this again, but i followed your suggestion and i was able to put the categories with CASE's by giving them a numerical value of order of importance and then taking the MIN later on to assign a category, this sped up considerably my query, if you want info i can post my solution later, thanks.